# A chat room for posting or discussing SE questions from other sites related to GIS

Tags: discussion, chat

Most SE sites will have a general purpose chat room as a sort-of catch-all; a way to:

- ping a moderator
- ask for advice about the topicality of an issue before posting it or writing an explanation in a meta question)
- leave notice of and/or discuss a question on a different site that could benefit from some GIS expertise or be of specific interest, such as [Why doesn't Wolfram Alpha show low gravitational acceleration for the Hudson Bay?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16787/6031)

But this site doesn't have one of these.

Might it be a good idea for one to exist?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis

Comment: @PolyGeo Indeed I was! It seems that once it was frozen it became invisible to me. Thank you for the unfreeze! :-)